# git using different version of vim than zsh

Tags: vim, git, zsh

I've got a plugin called YouCompleteMe installed in vim. When vim starts with this plugin installed, it will raise a warning if the version of vim is under the minimum required.

I'm using vim 7.3.754, which is able to run YCM, but when I execute commands like `git merge` or `git commit --amend`, I see the warning:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim 7.3.584+
```

My question is: **why is git using a different version of vim than zsh, and how can I get it to use the same version?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `man git-var` git determines the editor using this sequence:

> The order of preference is the $GIT_EDITOR environment
>              variable, then core.editor configuration, then $VISUAL, then $EDITOR, and then finally vi.

I suppose you haven't set any of these variables, so git takes `vi` -- which usually runs vim in the *vi compatible mode* (depending on you distribution).

So, check where yor up-to-date vim is located:

```
which vim
```

Then define this executable as the default git editor:

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

Alternatively, it's no bad idea to set `$VISUAL`. Other programs also use this environment variable, too. To do that, include

```
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim
```

in your `~/.zshrc` and do `source ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why git might have been ignoring `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR` and `~/.gitconfig`?  The only way that I could get this to work was to explicitly set `$GIT_EDITOR`.

Comment: @SeanHill: Have you checked if you have the `core.editor` defined somewhere in your git config? As this take precedence over `$VISUAL`and `$EDITOR` this might look as if these environment variables are ignored.

Comment: Yeah, setting core.editor to `/usr/local/bin/vim` was ignored also.  Git was using another version of vim no matter what I put in `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR` or `core.editor`.  The only thing it will respect is `$GIT_EDITOR`.

Comment: To be clear, it was using `vi` even though I had set the other variables and `$GIT_EDITOR` was not set at all.  I'm using version 2.1.1 of git.

Comment: @SeanHill: Probably it's best if you open up a own question on your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I might later... just came across this, and it helped me figure out that I needed to set `GIT_EDITOR`.  I forgot to vote you up... just did that now.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Git uses either `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` or `$GIT_EDITOR` or the editor you specified for `core.editor` in `~/.gitconfig`.